# Can I use a clamp meter to identify wires running to overhead fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have this mess of wires in a junction box of a stucco house (built 30 years ago).  Couple of these are going to the overhead fan in the room.  Will a simple clamp meter help me identify the relevant wires?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "clamp meter" you mean a non-contact AC Ammeter, and if the circuit can be loaded enough to trigger the reading.  Yes, you should be able to isolate the circuit using such a meter.  (Keep in mind that this type of meter only registers AC current so you must have current flowing for it to read.)

On a related note, however, that box looks to be severely overloaded.  You may want to consider upgrading it as this may be unsafe.

Comment: I have both AC and DC amp clamp meters. As far as tracking by a specific load a clamp can be very handy, I used to use a Holliday light flasher on a large wattage light bulb 150-300w putting my clamp on the line I knew within 1 second if it was the correct circuit, today I use modern electronic tools but this is how I used to trace circuits before the circuit seekers , breaker finders, To tell the truth it was quite accurate . I have had the breaker finders be wrong many times but since there was a pulsing load I never had this method be wrong.

Comment: @jwh20: By "overloaded" I assume you mean cramped into a small space?  It's a real pain, in that the copper wires are incredibly stiff, to the point they barely bend by hand.  I am told this is good in terms of safety, but it's otherwise terribly inconvenient for handling.

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes, you understand my meaning.  It appears that there are too many wires/connections for the volume of that box.  But it's hard to tell.  Generally if it's difficult to handle, the box is too crowded.

Comment: @jwh20 Thank you for the clarification.  I would love to be able to insert a new and bigger box in there but it requires concrete demolition which generates so much dust.